# formidable - SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0 when sending POST request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, formidable

I am building the backend for creating blog posts for my web application while following a tutorial.

The technologies I am using are MongoDB, express.js, **formidable**

The relevant files are:

**server.js**

```
......

// middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());

// cors
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    app.use(cors({origin: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`}));
}

// routes middleware
app.use('/api', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', userRoutes);
app.use('/api', blogRoutes);
app.use('/api', categoryRoutes);
app.use('/api', tagRoutes);

// port
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// Listening App
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on PORT ${port}`);
})
```

**Blog Schema Model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            min: 3,
            max: 160,
            required: true
        },
        slug: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            index: true
        },
        body: {
            type: {},
            required: true,
            min: 200,
            max: 2000000
        },
        excerpt: {
            type: String,
            max: 1000
        },
        mtitle: {
            type: String
        },
        mdesc: {
            type: String
        },
        photo: {
            data: Buffer,
            contentType: String
        },
        categories: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Category', required: true }],
        tags: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Tag', required: true }],
        postedBy: {
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    },
    { timestamp: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

**blog.js (Routes)**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { create } = require('../controllers/blog');

const { requireSignin, adminMiddleware } = require('../controllers/auth');

router.post('/blog', requireSignin, adminMiddleware, create);

module.exports = router;
```

**blog.js (controllers)**

```
const Blog = require('../models/blog');
const Category = require('../models/category');
const Tag = require('../models/tag');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const slugify = require('slugify');
const stripHtml = require('string-strip-html');
const _ = require('lodash');
const { errorHandler } = require('../helpers/dbErrorHandler');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Image could not upload'
            });
        }

        const { title, body, categories, tags } = fields;

        let blog = new Blog();
        blog.title = title;
        blog.body = body;
        blog.slug = slugify(title).toLowerCase();
        blog.mtitle = `${title} | ${process.env.APP_NAME}`;
        blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160));
        blog.postedBy = req.user._id;

        if (files.photo) {
            if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: 'Image should be less then 1mb in size'
                });
            }
            blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
            blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
        }

        blog.save((err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: errorHandler(err)
                });
            }
            res.json(result);
        });
    });
};
```

Problem: When I POST a request using Postman in order to create a category which is as follows:
[image: Posting Request]

Headers and other data I used are:
[image: Request Headers]

I am getting this error:
[image: Main Error]

The things which I observed are:

1. As I am following a particular tutorial, the formidable versions might be updated, hence the syntax error. Still, I wasn't able to find any particular solutions for handling `IncomingForm()` using **formidable**.
2. The error message doesn't show any particular line of written code so it is hard to figure out where the actual issue lies.
3. I have checked my blog schema model definition and it looks fine couldn't figure out anything wrong there.

Currently, I am unable to find a solution to this issue as I may be unaware of any minor mistakes I may have committed.

I have attached all my relevant files and I can produce any other files if needed.

I request you to please go through my issue as I am stuck here and couldn't proceed further.

Thanks.

Comment: switch from form-data to raw and choose json from there

Comment: @Jimmy I have tried this but the request won't send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this answer if anyone encounters this error in the future.

**The above answers may be applicable to any other situations so must try them too.**

My Fix:

I was using `formidable version 2.0.1` along with the app middleware as follows:

- `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));`
- `app.use(express.json());`
- `app.use(morgan('dev'));`
- `app.use(cookieParser());`

I have found out that formidable doesn't work with these above middleware and it is not possible to POST images using formidable.

**My Solution:**
I found out about `express-formidable`.

```
npm install express-formidable
```

After installing this, I also fixed the syntax(old) with new i.e.

```
blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.filepath);
blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.mimetype;
```

**`filepath` and `mimetype`**

After this, when I tested it with postman, I also set the Content-Type to default (checked the hidden header which is default) and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

While you are sending data using form data. You set
`Content-Type: application/json` wrong.
Set `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

Remove middleware app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json())
And
app.use(cookieParser())

From server.js and then try

Comment: This post seems incomplete. Please add more details to clearly outline the problem and how this problem can be resolved.

Comment: I have tried the solution you provided. So, when I removed all these middleware, the `form.parse()` error is thrown i.e. `Image could not upload`.

As far as I know my original issue occurred because of the image upload function using `formidable` library.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same project, the problem was actually in the mdesc, not formidable, and i added this:

```
posts.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160)).result.toString();
```

By adding `.toString()` after `stripHtml(...).result`, you convert the value to a string, resolving the cast error.

And don't forget about this:

```
+files.photo.filepath
```